# How to get whitespace between html tags

Tags: html, elm

Using Elm's `Html` module, the output do not have any whitespace between html tags. But for inline displayed tags, whitespace has a function and makes the browser display empty space between them.

```
div []
    [ strong [] [ text "Key:" ]
    , span [] [ text "value" ]
    , text "(extra)"
    ]
```

Results in:

```
<div><strong>Key:</strong><span>value</span>(extra)</div>
```

Shown in a browser as: Key:value(extra)

#### Desired result

The desired html must have some kind of whitespace:

```
<div>
<strong>Key:</strong>
<span>value</span>
(extra)
</div>
```

Shown in browser as: Key: value (extra)

Comment: Can you not just be explicit about the whitespace?

Comment: Well, maybe. But it is very unelegant!

Comment: That is what it actually is though. Contrarily, I find vertical whitespace magically transforming into horizontal whitespace inelegant, and also overly complicated and error-prone. I generally prefer explicitness because it tends to lead to much fewer surprises. There are exceptions though, if something is tedious and frequent enough that I'm likely to actually remember the special rules of magic. But this doesn't seem like one of those cases to me, mostly because this situation seems to occur very infrequently. But  that's just my two cents...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a wrapper for `Html` tags as follows:

```
type alias HtmlTag msg =
   List (Html.Attribute msg) -> List (Html msg) -> Html msg


interspaced : HtmlTag msg -> HtmlTag msg
interspaced fn =
   \attr content -> fn attr (content |> List.intersperse (text " "))


main : Html msg
main =
    interspaced div []
        [ strong [] [ text "Key:" ]
        , span [] [ text "value" ]
        , text "(extra)"
        ]
```

Comment: The usage here looks better than @glennsl's proposal since you don't have the extra indentation and paranthesis

Comment: It does look better, but it won't work with most user defined view functions since they usually don't follow the same shape. And so it's actually more specialized, not generalized. /pedant

Comment: It's fair to say that my phrasing is inaccurate so I will correct it once we agree on a better formulation. But the wrapper works on all `Html` tags, so it will work *in* user defined view functions. Your solution won't work on "most user defined view functions" either since it takes a `List (Html msg)`, which "most user defined view functions" don't produce. Do you have a suggestion regarding the phrasing @glennsl?

Comment: Rename `MarkupFunction` to `HtmlTag` and replace the first line by something about wrapping `Html` tags to remove ambiguity?

Comment: The phrasing isn't very important, I'm just being a pedant. But specialization for `Html` functions would be more accurate.

Comment: Space between elements only makes sense if you have a list of elements, and it would work on any user-defined view function which takes a list of child elements no matter what its shape otherwise is. This doesn't, so that's the essential trade-off.

Comment: You could generalize your solution a bit by just not following the shape of `Html` function exactly, but only requiring the last argument to be a list of elements, which by convention I think most user-defined functions would have anyway, and passing in element functions partially applied with the attributes. The type would be `withSpacing : (List (Html msg) -> Html msg) -> Html msg` and its use with standard `Html` functions: `withSpacing (div []) [ strong ... ]`

Comment: That type came about a bit wrong... I've updated my answer with an actual working example instead.

Comment: I mean, you're not wrong, but I don't see when you'll ever have a `List (Html msg)` without a tag to display it. Your approach is more general, but I don't see that as a goal in itself. Wrapping without parentheses appears cleaner and more readable, and as far as I can tell there's no actual trade-off being made.

Comment: If you use any UI framework, like `elm-mdc` or `elm-bulma`, or if you make your own, you won't necessarily use tags directly and the view functions usually won't have the same shape.

Answer (score 5):

You could just put whitespace between the elements manually:

```
div []
    [ strong [] [ text "Key:" ]
    , text " "
    , span [] [ text "value" ]
    , text " "
    , text "(extra)"
    ]
```

Or if you want something more generic you can easily write a function to do so using `List.intersperse`, e.g.:

```
withSpacing : List (Html msg) -> List (Html msg)
withSpacing =
    List.intersperse (text " ")


main : Html msg
main =
    div []
        (withSpacing
            [ strong [] [ text "Key:" ]
            , span [] [ text "value" ]
            , text "(extra)"
            ]
        )
```

Or with even more convenience, based on the reasonable assumption that you'll be applying it to a function that takes a list of child elements to produce a single element:

```
withSpacing : (List (Html msg) -> Html msg) -> List (Html msg) -> Html msg
withSpacing element =
    List.intersperse (text " ") >> element


main : Html msg
main =
    withSpacing (div [])
        [ strong [] [ text "Key:" ]
        , span [] [ text "value" ]
        , text "(extra)"
        ]
```